# redmine example conf

Tags: apache, redmine, redmine-plugins

ruby script/rails server webrick -e production with no error, all run

but

redmine>admin>plugins>redmine_git_plugins>configure

500 internal error

apache > redmine.conf

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger
 4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5 PassengerDefaultRuby
 /usr/bin/ruby NameVirtualHost *:80

"VirtualHost *:80"

DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public

"/VirtualHost"

[cgi](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Redmine_203_with_Subversion_and_LDAP_Authentication_%28for_Redmine_and_Subversion_through_Redmine%29_on_Centos_6_i386_-_detailed#Getting-Apache-to-work-with-FastCGI) with this error fix link ?

Comment: use some markup in the question and state what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question but this might help

```
 # These modules must be enabled : passenger
<VirtualHost *:80>
# ServerName my.domain.name
# this is the passenger config
RailsEnv production
# create a link in /var/lib/redmine/default/passenger to
/usr/share/redmine
PassengerAppRoot /var/lib/redmine/default/passenger
SetEnv X_DEBIAN_SITEID "default"
Alias "/plugin_assets/" /var/cache/redmine/default/
plugin_assets/
DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public
<Directory "/usr/share/redmine/public">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```